# Can I model a double convex lens

Tags: modeling, depth-of-field

I'm fairly new to blender and not a graphics person by any stretch of the imagination. I've been having some success though modelling semi-reflective glass for a project I wish to build (physically) and I'm wondering if it is possible to model the effects of a lens. The lens I wish to model is a double-convex type. It has a diameter of 120mm and a focal-length of 301mm. Is this something that can be modelled in blender and if so, how? I'd like to be able to position the camera close to this lens and reproduce the magnifying effects of the lens on the scene behind the lens as well as depth-of-field effects.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried yet? :)

Comment: Regarding modeling, this should be possible. Regarding materials - it depends. Maybe related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/can-blender-be-used-for-simple-optical-modeling

Comment: Of course I misread the question, and wasted a few hours  building a model of a double concaved lense: :-/ ![Sample render](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=104618). [.blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42543).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create something like the following. You can also adjust the *IOR* to your liking; this is just a sample at *1.2*.

*Result with Shady Puck in the background:*

[image]

*Mesh sideview profile:*

[image]

## Modeling

Start by keying <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and going to *Mesh > Sphere*. Key <kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. Key <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to enter *Right Orthographic* view. Key <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode* and *Wireframe View*, respectively. Key <kbd>B</kbd> for **Box Select** and drag while holding down your <kbd>LMB</kbd> to select the following vertices.

[image]

Key <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> to scale the selected vertices down to a more lens-like shape. Key <kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> to slide them over. You now have half a double convex lens. You should see something like the following.

[image]

Key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice to deselect all vertices. Key <kbd>B</kbd> for **Box Select** and drag while holding down your <kbd>LMB</kbd> to select the following vertices.

[image]

Key <kbd>X</kbd> and choose *Vertices*. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of *Edit Mode* and key <kbd>Z</kbd> to exit *Wireframe View*. Go to the *Properties panel > Object modifiers tab* and add a *Mirror modifier*. Make sure *Z* is checked under *Axis:* and nothing else. Your settings should look like the following.

[image]

Add a *Subdivision surface modifier*. Set the *View:* value to *3* and the *Render:* value to *4*.

[image]

Key <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*. Go to *Tools tab > Edit dropdown > Shading:* and select *Smooth*.
You are now done with modeling.

## Materials

This is where the magic happens. Go to the *Properties panel > Materials tab* and add a *Glass BSDF* shader. Note that you will have to be in *Cycles Render* for this to work. Play with the *IOR:* as you wont.

*Materials tab:*

[image]

You now have a fully completed double convex lens.

## Further Reading

Many of the techniques from this piece are gathered from tutor4u's awesome [Focused Text Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnAsjyRq854&index=9&list=PLzmyR17f55-L9CJxL_Ymz2A79zL17J80B) tutorial.

## .blend file

The following is the .blend file with the lens and Shady Puck text from the first image.

[image]

Comment: Any idea concerning the DoF effect (without the compositor) ?

Comment: @lemon Without the compositor, not off the top of my head. I might be able to figure something out with enough research. If you have an idea, though, feel free to add it somewhere towards the end.

Comment: @user1602842 If you like my answer, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark in the upper left corner of my answer. It would help me greatly and make me very happy!

Comment: Shady Puck, if you're still there, I was able to reproduce your lens from scratch, great tutorial, however when I try to use the lens in my existing scene, I'm unable to render the other materials and textures correctly. In Cycles Render mode, everything turns out grainy at best, although the lens works. I've tried applying new materials to the other surfaces but couldn't get anything to look realistic. Is there any way to render standard textures, such as wooden floors, while in Cycles Render mode?

Comment: Check the settings in the _Properties panel > Render tab > Sampling_ and _Light Paths_ drop downs from my .blend file. Also make sure there is enough light. If you still have issues, comment your .blend file and I will look at it.

Comment: Not to worry, I'm getting the hang of it now after reading some tutorials and watching some videos. Very impressive results, although I see that I will need to get a better graphics card as my old g-force seems to render nothing with the GPU. All the best!

Comment: Is there a reason why the "y" is distorted?

Comment: @MicroMachine I’m not 100% sure why that happens, but I believe that it is related to the amount of *Subdivision surface* subdivisions.

Comment: @ShadyPuck could it be because it's seen through the polar end of the sphere? What if we make a lens out of a roundcube or flatten a sphere on its edge instead?

Comment: @MicroMachine That sounds reasonable. I’d encourage you to try it, if you’re interested! Let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: @ShadyPuck Just tried it - RoundCube creates less distortions even with 3 or more subdivisions! I assume the umbrella-shape of the polar end of the sphere creates artifacts when spheres are used to make lenses with their poles up

Comment: That works with Eevee renderer too (2.81.16).

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem could be broken down into three separate issues:

1. **Modelling** - In theory, geometry-wise you should be able to model "anything" you like, there really aren't that many constraints imposed. A convex lens is a relatively simple geometry should not be too hard to model.

   Whether Blender is the adequate tool for this is another matter. If you want real mathematical rigor and precision a NURBS modeling software may be more adequate although it is perfectly possible to do it in Blender with fair amount of
2. **Lens Effect** - If you plan on using Blender Cycles it *is* a physically accurate rendering engine, and it can even simulate a [Pinhole Camera](https://bensimonds.com/2013/03/04/cycles-experiment-pinhole-camera/) whether or not it can accurately recreate your lens is a matter of testing but all points in that direction at [least for the distortion part](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38139/how-do-i-create-a-magnified-glass-effect-in-cycles).

   As for the depth of field I am no longer sure, but it's a matter of testing yourself.
3. **Actual Camera** - Now I am not much into optics, but would it not be a lot easier to use Blender Cycles physical camera settings to simulate the camera effect?

   You can define a real world focal lens, sensor size, and even sampled depth of field with distance and size settings. Maybe this is enough to simulate the optics directly without having worry too much about physical accuracy of the model, although you may still want some form of simplified representation for your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot Duarte Farrajota Ramos. I'm going to look in to this. I guess Blender Cycles must be an addon. Doesn't look like it came with my install of blender (2.77 on Linux) but I'll try and track it down. All the best!

Comment: Cycles is one of the two default rendering engines built into Blender by default (the other being Blender Internal), you should be able to select it from the drop down menu in the window header towards the top of the screen. https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/index.html

Comment: Yes, found it - and it was using that renderer by default. Thanks again I'll read up on these links.

Comment: Actually no it wasn't - it got switched over when I loaded Shady Puck's blender file

Comment: You can freely switch between the two at any time but have in mind that they are completely different and separate rendering systems. Materials shaders, and textures created for Cycles won't work in Blender internal and opposite is also true.