# How do I make a magnifying glass plane?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to make a glass plane that zooms in whatever you see behind it, I tried this material from [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79749/zoom-window-magnification) but it didn't work

[image]

I think what this is supposed to do is to scale all the light that comes through the Z Normals?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38139/how-do-i-create-a-magnified-glass-effect-in-cycles)  Also please provide link to other question / answer mentioned.

Comment: For that to work (the IOR 0.0 trick) you need to have the surface normal pointing the correct way - the opposite way to that you would expect. The IOR of zero will effectively direct the incoming rays directly along the Normal - so it can be used to bend incoming (parallel) rays as if the surface acts lens. See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/115868/29586

Answer (score 1):

1. Model a magnifying glass lens (biconvex)
2. Set its color to white
3. Use **raytrace** transparency

Comment: Could you elaborate on what raytraced transparency is?

Comment: It's transparency+refractions. See more ->  https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/dev/render/blender_render/materials/properties/transparency.html