# Create a working microscope in Blender?

Tags: modeling, light

I am modeling a microscope, and am wondering if it is actually possible to make the microscope would *so that* it functions like a light-refractory microscope in real life. (Not an electron scanning microscope).
I.e. it has glass material lenses to refract light and magnify objects .1mm in real world size. Is this possible in Blender, and if so, how could I do this?

What I essentially want is to actually use a series of lenses to magnify an object in .1mm real world size ***instead*** of using a separate render.

In one sense, I am asking if it is possible to *create* an object in Blender at **.1mm** (microscopic level) ***real world size***, and be able to use a working modeled microscope to be able to see it through a camera's lens.

I'm *not* looking to be practical about viewing a microscopic object, so that's why I don't want to just make a separate render of it, so I want it to be physically light based.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38139/how-do-i-create-a-magnified-glass-effect-in-cycles

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9093/76173

Comment: Or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56812/can-i-model-a-double-convex-lens

Comment: Or: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79749/zoom-window-magnification

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to do that though. Rendering another scene for the time you are viewing things through the microscope will be a lot more practical.

Comment: I want to be able to magnify a minuscule object with a series of "microscope" lenses.

Comment: Pretty much answered by comments. Model a number of lenses, align them as if in microscope place a camera (for eye) check rendered result   As commented may need to use Luxrender.  Looking forward to the result you come up with.

Comment: I do use luxcore render. Could I make an object .1mm or smaller and be able to view it with the lenses without changing the world size? It would be extremely helpful if you could post an answer with a picture of this working. I haven't been able to do so yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for fun, you can also get good results with Cycles.

Glass shader with IOR = 1,6 (same as [Crown glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_glass_(optics)) used in microscopes)
And a rather simple microscope setup.

*Original image with a tiny Suzanne*
[image]

*Magnified using a microscope*
[image]

*Diagram of used setup*
[image]

*Notes:*
Cycles, 100 samples + Intel Denoiser
I'm sure better results can be achieved by playing with the lens setup.
**Bottom line, it works** :).

[image]

Comment: Could you post the blend file for this setup? Your answer doesn't really explain why you chose this configuration or what the lens sizes are.

Comment: Hi :). Sure, I edited the post. But bear in mind, this was just an artistic exercise. I know nothing about microscopes, so I just used a [random microscope diagram](https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/microscopy/understanding-microscopes-and-objectives/) and played with the setup until it looked 'good'.

Answer (score 6):

The comments already give you all the hints, you can use the default settings.

1. Add two lenses in between the camera and the objects.
2. Assign a glass material to the lenses.

[image: setup]

With the lenses enabled, the object are appear magnified. To remove the distorsion, we would have to research about lenses. To remove the bloom (sorry), I would have to know the basics of LuxCore.

[image: result]